# ERROR 1064 a la creación de usuarios en una base de datos MySQL

Tags: mysql, debian, debian-9

Acabo de crear una base de datos MySQL en un servidor Debian alojado en una máquina virtual.

Me dijeron que recuperara las contraseñas o creara unas para hozana_data, hozana_metabase y hozana_backup.

Luego conectar a mysql como root `mysql -u root -p` y ejecutar:

```
CREATE DATABASE hozana_data;
CREATE DATABASE hozana_archive;
INSERT INTO mysql.user (User,Host,authentication_string,ssl_cipher,x509_issuer,x509_subject) VALUES('hozana_data','localhost',PASSWORD('*********'),'','','');
INSERT INTO mysql.user (User,Host,authentication_string,ssl_cipher,x509_issuer,x509_subject) VALUES('hozana_metabase','localhost',PASSWORD('*********'),'','','');
INSERT INTO mysql.user (User,Host,authentication_string,ssl_cipher,x509_issuer,x509_subject) VALUES('hozana_backup','localhost',PASSWORD('*********'),'','','');
```

Lo he intentado pero he obtenido :

```
miked@debian:/tmp$ mysql -u root -p
mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf at line 29.
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 13
Server version: 8.0.25 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CREATE DATABASE hozana_data;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE hozana_archive;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO mysql.user (User,Host,authentication_string,ssl_cipher,x509_issuer,x509_subject) VALUES('hozana_data','localhost',PASSWORD('hozana_data'),'','','');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('hozana_data'),'','','')' at line 1
```

Creo que la razón es que entendí mal esto *"recuperarar las contraseñas o crear unas para hozana_data, hozana_metabase y hozana_backup."*

Comment: Seguro que te han pedido lo que estas haciendo: crear nuevas passwords. Pero veo que estas creando usuarios directamente en la table mysql.users, no veo el error pero el servidor si que lo ve. Así que porque no creas los usuarios mediante CREATE USER? Creo que es más apropiado.

Comment: Estás usando la versión 8 de MySQL en la cual no existe ya la función `PASSWORD()` que usas en tu instrucción `INSERT`, la misa **fue removida a partir de MySQL 8**: *"This function is deprecated in MySQL 5.7 and is removed in MySQL 8.0"*. Por eso te da error de sintaxis, porque no reconoce esta parte de la instrucción: `PASSWORD('hozana_data')`. [Revisa el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) y considera actualizar tu código con [otra función de encriptado](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html).